# TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-saga

I want to move device to created group(group device is shown only if any one device is selected) however i am getting an error of

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Also in createGroupSuccess, updatedDevice object should be passed but when i console in createGroupSuccess action i get whole device object. That is why i could not add the group in the device object when trying to move.

```
function* createGroup(action) {
  const device = yield select(selectDevice(), action);
  const updatedDevice = { id: device.get('id') };
  // const group = fromJS(action.group);
  // if (action.deviceId) {
  //   group = device.getIn(['device_group', action.deviceId]);
  //   group = group.mergeDeep(action.group);
  //   console.log('group inside if block', group);
  // }
  updatedDevice.device_group = action.group;
  if (action.group) {
    yield call(POST(`/device/${updatedDevice.id}`, createGroupSuccess, createGroupError, updatedDevice));
  }
}

function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeEvery(CREATE_GROUP, createGroup);
}


export function createGroup(group, deviceId) {
  return {
    type: CREATE_GROUP,
    group,
    deviceId,
  };
}

export function createGroupSuccess(device) {
  console.log('group in success', device);
  return {
    type: CREATE_GROUP_SUCCESS,
    device,
  };
}

export function createGroupError(error) {
  return {
    type: CREATE_GROUP_ERROR,
    error,
  };
}

case CREATE_GROUP:
  return state
    .set('loading', true)
    .set('error', null);

case CREATE_GROUP_SUCCESS:
  console.log('success', action);
  return state.set('loading', false).set('error', null)
    .setIn(['devices', action.device.data.id, 'device_group', action.device.data]);
```

**my device object is**

```
device:Object
  data:Object
    description: null,
    device_group: null,
    id: "7eb006d6db50479aa47f887da0d4f10e",
    name: "Fan Speed"
```

Where have i done the mistake in creating the group in the device object which is being selected while creating the group?

**UPDATE**

```
export function POST(apiUri, onSuccess, onError, data) {
 return dataLoader(apiUri, onSuccess, onError, data);
}

export function dataLoader(apiUri, onSuccess, onError, data) {
  return function* () {  // eslint-disable-line func-names
    const requestURL = `${API_BASE}${apiUri}`;
    try {
      let options;
      if (data !== undefined) {
        options = {
          method: 'POST',
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': Cookies.get('csrftoken'),
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
          },
        };
      }
      const response = yield call(requestJSON, requestURL, options);
      yield put(onSuccess(response));
    } catch (e) {
      let error = null;
      try {
        error = yield call(() => e.response.json());
      } catch (_) {
        error = {
          errors: [{
            'code': e.response.status,
            'msg': e.response.statusText,
          }],
        };
      }
      yield put(onError(error));
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: where is your POST function? I guess you are checking response status on that.

Comment: @FazalRasel i have updated my question. createGroupSuccess action is also not getting the right argument. By right argument, i mean updatedDeviec object should be passed with id and device_group, i believe but is getting whole device object with device_group null

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing status with sendStatus